# "Attic stairs" equivelent in an attic "hatch" size hole?

Tags: attic, stairs

The new place I'm moving into has a hatch size hole for the attic. It is roughly square and has no stairs or anything, its just a hatch that can be accessed by ladder.

I'd really like to make more use of the attic, and I'd love attic stairs, but I don't want to modify the ceiling to accommodate it. Is there any sort of product that will fit into the hatch (or possibly screw into it, etc.) that provides the convenience of attic stairs without the added footprint?

Comment: What size is the hole?  they do make fold down stairs, but the hole has to be large enough to accommodated them.

Comment: See [this](http://www.bessler.com/) or [this](http://www.rainbowatticstair.com/attic-stairs-products/prestige-folding-attic-stairs.cfm) they have many styles, but they all depend on the opening size.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.wernerladder.com/newprods/televator.php

You might see if this Werner "Televator" ladder would fit. I was looking for something similar, but my attic opening is framed at 20"x24" rather than 22"x22". The Werner has received good reviews at amazon.